# S3 Presigned URL Multiple Content Disposition Headers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-disposition, pre-signed-url

I have an S3 bucket having PDF files as objects and all of them are private. I create an S3 Presigned URL programmatically to get the object. It works fine. Now, I want it to be previewable as a PDF. Every object already has a `Content-Type` header set to `application/pdf`. Now, if I set the `response-content-disposition` header as a query parameter, it gets set but doesn't override the already existing `Content-disposition` header, instead, it creates a new one. If I set the `Content-Disposition` header in the metadata of the S3 object instead of adding it in the S3 Presigned URL as a query parameter, it still shows 2 headers. Is this some kind of bug on the AWS S3 side?

Below is the screenshot of the Response Header for reference.

[image: Con]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the resulting headers are different. One has "D", another - "d". So "Content-Disposition" and "Content-disposition" are different headers according to the sender. This header is not a multi-value one. So The last appended value should overwrite a previous value. But for a receiver (browser) they are the same. And a browser took the last one (with attachment value). Probably, proper registers should do the trick initially.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have solved this issue using the latest API available for this thing from AWS SDK for NodeJS using the following code:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const AWS_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 'v4';

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: <aws-access-key>,
  secretAccessKey: <aws-secret-access-key>,
  region: <aws-region>,
  signatureVersion: AWS_SIGNATURE_VERSION
});

/**
 * Return a signed document URL given a Document instance
 * @param  {object} document Document
 * @return {string}          Pre-signed URL to document in S3 bucket
 */
const getS3SignedDocumentURL = (docName) => {
  const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: <aws-s3-bucket-name>,
    Key: <aws-s3-object-key>,
    Expires: <url-expiry-time-in-seconds>,
    ResponseContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${docName}"`
  });

  return url;
};

/**
 * Return a signed document URL previewable given a Document instance
 * @param  {object} document Document
 * @return {string}          Pre-signed URL to previewable document in S3 bucket
 */
const getS3SignedDocumentURLPreviewable = (docName) => {
  const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: <aws-s3-bucket-name>,
    Key: <aws-s3-object-key>,
    Expires: <url-expiry-time-in-seconds>,
    ResponseContentDisposition: `inline; filename="${docName}"`
  });

  return url;
};

module.exports = {
  getS3SignedDocumentURL,
  getS3SignedDocumentURLPreviewable
};
```

*Note: Don't forget to replace the placeholders (<...>) with actual values to make it work.*

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have read an aws document here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_RequestSyntax and it says the response header can be override, I tried but it's not working. 

Your solution is totally working for me.

Comment: @Lolo., My pleasure. :)

Comment: is there any document mentioned what parameter can developer pass into the getSignedUrl? I'm reading the SDK document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)  and it's not mention it

Comment: @Lolo., The document link that you have shared says the following: "See the given operation for the expected operation parameters." If the operation is "getObject" then the possible parameters can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Answer (score 3):

It's strange how often we overlook things like filenames where `comma (,)` could be common if it is user generated name.
While setting `response-content-disposition` make sure to strip special character or properly escape the filename attribute

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6745788/8813684 for more details